# How do I return an array to this function in php?

Tags: php, android, sql, arrays, json

I have some php code here. I am trying to get rows from my database turn them into a JSON array so that I can use it in an app I have also made. I'm having difficulty passing the array to the from DBOperations.php to my Function.php.

Here is the code for DBOperations.php:

```
//Read from diary table and enter results into an array
public function readDiaryOperation($email) 
{
    $query = $this-> conn -> prepare("SELECT title,entry FROM diary WHERE email = :email");
    $query -> execute(array(':email' => $email));

    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $json['success'] = 0;
        $json['message'] = 'No Data found';     
        $json['myintro'] = '';

        return json_encode($json);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my Functions.php

```
//Login user after checking that the user exists within the database or the      fields are empty
public function readDiary($email) 
{
$db = $this -> db;

if (!empty($email)) 
{
if ($db -> readDiaryOperation($email)) 
{
   $result =  $db -> readDiaryOperation($email);

   if(!$result) 
   {
        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "Read Diary Failure - Error Code 1";
        return json_encode($response);
   } 
   else 
   {
        $response["result"] = "success";
        $response["message"] = "Read Diary Operation Successful";
        $response["diary"] = $result;
        return json_encode($response);
   }
} 
else 
{
  $response["result"] = "failure";
  $response["message"] = "Read Diary Failure - Error Code 2";
  return json_encode($response);
}
} 
else 
{
     return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
}
}
```

The $email is set using retrofit from my app.

Answer (score 0):

You call your function readDiaryOperation twice, what means, that query always be double executed:

```
if ($db -> readDiaryOperation($email)) 
{
   $result =  $db -> readDiaryOperation($email);
```

By the way, function readDiaryOperation always return array, so that condition:

```
if(!$result)
{
```

will be always false and never executed.

So that's no matter how many rows you found. Code will always return valid result:

```
$response["result"] = "success";
$response["message"] = "Read Diary Operation Successful";
$response["diary"] = $result;
return json_encode($response);
```

That exaclly output do you require ?